# Access to laravel .env file

Tags: php, wordpress, git, laravel

Hi I am developing an application with laravel 5.5. I want to build a setup similar to Wordpress, and I want to automatically save the database information to the .env file, so that's how I do it, or how to access the .env file.

Comment: See: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv - laraval uses that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prepare the contents of the `.env` file and save it:

```
\File::put(base_path('.env'), $contents);
```

But I'd say it's a bad idea to do that. You should keep the data in DB or config files.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. But I could not understand why it was a bad idea, and it will still be stored in the database. I only use it on an interface so that the user can enter the database information.